# How to make your apache application accessible within network

Tags: local-area-network

I have a Windows XP machine where I have installed WAMP and made a PHP based web application. I can access the web application from within this machine by using the browser and pointing to: `http://localhost/myApp/` --- and the page loads fine.

Now I want this site (`http://localhost/myApp`) to be accessible to all machines within the network (and may be later, to the general public as well). I am quite new to this, how do I make my site accessible to all machines within the network and to the general public in the internet?

I tried modifying the httpd.conf file in Apache (WAMP) by changing 
`Listen 80` to `Listen 10.10.10.10:80` (where I replaced `10.10.10.10` with the actual IP of this windows xp machine). I also tried "Put Online" feature in WAMP. None seem to work though.

How do I make it accessible?

Comment: [Don't do this.](http://serverfault.com/q/453617/126632) WampServer and its cousins are not designed or intended for production use.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I am just trying out once. I intend to go the normal route (with pure Apache installation) once my site is fully done. I just want, for now, all my computers within the same network to access this test site. How do I enable that?

Comment: OK.. figured it out.
If you want other computers (within your network) to access your site hosted in your localhost, then: 
1. go to httpd.conf (wamp - apache - httpd.conf)
2. search for "deny from" or "allow"
3. uncomment the line "deny from all"
4. add a new line "allow from all"
5. save httpd.conf file, and restart all services.

To access your site, from another machine, type http://ipAddress/yourSiteAddress
where ipAddress is the ipa address of your localhost machine (you can get this by doing a ifconfig - if in linux, or ipconfig from windows).

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a better solution is this:

For Apache 2.4.x

Find this section in the httpd.conf file, this change also corrects the syntax to use Apache 2.4 new syntax.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

And change it to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

    # This looks after 127.0.0.1 ::1 and localhost
    Require local
    # This should be the first 3 quartiles of the standard subnet ipaddress range
    Require ip 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

Or if you are still using Apache 2.2

Change the similiar section as follows

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost 
    # This should be the first 3 quartiles of the standard subnet ipaddress range
    Allow from 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

If you use the `Allow from all` methos you are actually allowing access from any ip address, even external internet ones. Potentially very dangerous.