# Installing APC on ubuntu

Tags: linux, php, xampp, alternative-php-cache

So I've got my server running Ubuntu with lampp (xampp for linux) running.
I want to implement a file upload progress bar, so I am trying to install APC. (Please do not suggest alternative plugins) I tried multiple tutorials, but the way I ended up using is running `apt-get install php-apc` this worked fine, no errors during installation, but then I tried running this command in php:

```
apc_fetch($somevar);
```

and it ended up failing with:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_fetch()
```

In my php.ini file I put `apc.rfc1867 = On;`. I also tried `extension=apc.so`, but that results in an internal server error. Other things I tried are:

- `apc.enabled = 1`
- `apc.shm_size = 32`
- `apc.rfc1867 = 1`

None of them worked, hopefully you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using lampp and then try to install an ubuntu-provided package on top. This is not going to work. Get rid of the uselessness that is lampp, and stick to using only Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Do you think there is any method apart from that, I mean the lampp setup works perfectly aside from that

Comment: @Florija Not likely. And you'll have to get rid of it before you deploy anyway. See [Why not use a WAMP stack?](http://serverfault.com/q/453617/126632)