# How to check if MySQL server is working or not?

Tags: mysql, ssh

I have installed Webuzo on my unmanaged VPS. I am not able to install any applications, since it is giving me errors such "Unable to connect to MySQL server". But through terminal, the MySQL status is running.

Can anybody help how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I think it unlikely you'll get much help here. Professional environments [almost never use these sorts of "stacks"](http://serverfault.com/q/453617/126632) to deploy web applications; they are generally designed for developers and enthusiasts, people at the very end of the long tail, and people who don't actually know how to administer a web site.

Comment: I remember installing it one by one. Not through LAMP or Webuzo.

Comment: `But through terminal, the MySQL status is running` <- How have you determined this? [You need to describe things with some level of detail that would be useful to a person who knows nothing about your environment](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Answer (score 46):

Many ways to do it - in your terminal:

`sudo service mysql status`

or

`ps aux | grep mysql`

What you're facing is probably authentication failure or database misspell.

Did you try logging in with same creds via Terminal?

`mysql -u <username> -p <database-name>`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Also check to what IP address the daemon is bound. Maybe you're using the wrong one and that is the reason for the failure?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the MySQL service status as follows :

`Root > service mysqld status

or

Root > ps aux | grep mysql

or

// Is MySQL listening to the required port

Root > lsof -i :3306`

You can check the status of the MySQL service from the Webuzo Enduser Panel >> Services Menu.
Guide : http://webuzo.com/wiki/Restart_services

As for your error "Unable to connect to MySQL server", are you able to create databases from the Webuzo Enduser Panel ?
Guide : http://webuzo.com/wiki/How_to_Create_and_Manage_MySQL_Databases

Did you change the MySQL root users' password ?
Password for the MySQL root user is in the file /var/webuzo/my.conf

If the MySQL service is running, try accessing the MySQL server from the terminal.

Hope it helps \m/

Comment: Correct first command is [sudo] service mysql status

Answer (score 2):

1. `lsof -i :3306 a`

and

2. `mysqladmin processlist`

Answer (score 1):

`ps uxa | grep mysqld`

If there is output, your mysqld is active. (Although it can be yet unreachable, but that will be your next question soon)

Answer (score 1):

Default MySQL server port is 3306, if it's running then you'll have to check for the right port being used:

```
# netstat -vulntp |grep -i mysql
```

If no results returned then you'll have to check your MySQL log.

Answer (score 0):

"process is running" is not same as "service is available" for everywhere.

check your detail logs on both client and server side to find error detail, and check service connection status by manual connection:

```
$ mysql ...
```

from DB server locally, and from client.

I don't know about Webuzo. it's just general answer.