# Is it wise to install WAMP on Windows VPS in order to make use of already written PHP application?

Tags: windows

I got a request to put one web application written in PHP+MySql that runs normally on Linux machine (which is set up as web server) to Windows VPS.

I did some research and found out I could install WAMP and host the application via that practically the same way as I had it on my Linux machine, but since I don't have experience with this I'm asking you guys if this is a "valid option" or it's not suggested at all?

Comment: Do they already have _web sites_ on the Windows machine?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: no, they don't. But they have some GUI program they want to run on Windows server, and now they want to have all this together - saving one server, which I can't argue, it's a good point, but am struggling to see if that's the "way to go"

Comment: Ahh. [We've covered most all of this ground before](http://serverfault.com/q/453617/126632); this is a _very bad idea_ for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I did find that particular question that you referred when I was researching this "problem". However at the time I was sure my question had a little more diversity than that and was worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially there area several pitfalls in migrating an application across different machines with the same operating system, between different machines with compatible OS and particularly betwen machines running incompatible OS (where I'm classifying UNIX/BSD/Linux as 'compatible' operating systems). But without reading all the code I can't tel you whether you will be affected by these problems.

That you needed to do some research to find out about WAMP suggests that you will struggle if these issues manifest for your application.

Why do you want to move it? Why not a Linux VM?

Comment: It's not that I want to move it - client has a wish (since they will need some other programs that run only on Windows) to have everything on one server.