# Setting GoDaddy SSL on Wamp server

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I recently had to change the a ecommerce website for a client, and the new site is now on an EC2 instance that is running WAMP.

The client already has a GoDaddy SSL certificate, however, it is getting me really confusing how if I can use it as it is. I downloaded for Apache and it has two .crt files.

I don't have access for previously generated CSR or private key or pem file. Sorry am really new to this -> How to proceed?

FYI: I am following the steps as here: http://mrkeck.com/2012/07/14/ssl-on-wamp-server/

Comment: Whoever bought the certificate has the private key, and must provide it to you.

Comment: "How to proceed?" [Stop using WAMP](http://serverfault.com/questions/453617/why-not-use-a-wamp-stack). That should be step #1.

Comment: @EEAA I would be switching soon to Laravel on Nginx. How every just making sure there is this legacy thing in place. Thanks for this.

Comment: Micheal, I am following this tutorial: http://mrkeck.com/2012/07/14/ssl-on-wamp-server/

Do I need to ask for the .pem file as well?

Comment: You need the private key file, the certificate file (in standard PEM format) an the CA certificate to complete the certificate chain. Click the "Install Certificate" link on the instructions page you are using. It explains it all. Replace the Linux paths with Wndows paths.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. The client doesn't have a copy of the key, so I'll regenerate it. But that makes process a lot simpler for me.