# Can Windows Server run PHP and MySQL?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I know that PHP and MySQL are standard set for Apache server and Windows Server has own native SQL database.

But I have to migrate the system that is written for PHP/MySQL from Apache to Windows Server.

It is possible to install PHP & MySQL on Windows Server 2017 (or another version of it)? Best without virtual machines.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You could at least have tried to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

- [WAMP - Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- [XAMPP - Cross-Platform Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Or you could roll your own, see here: ["A Complete Guide to Installing MySQL and PHP with IIS"](http://www.drewslair.com/2015/09/installing-mysql-php-iis-complete-guide/) - MySQL will install as a stand alone, in exactly the same way it does on every system, and fast CGI can be configured as per [this MS article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis).

Comment: I think XAMPP is not really PHP/MySQL on Windows Server. It's Apache on top of Windows with PHP/MySQL on it. I look to install PHP/MySQL without Apache. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're confusing "Windows Server" with "IIS" - they are not the same thing. Apache and IIS are interchangeable, both however run on Windows server. That said, you can install PHP and MySQL for use with IIS, please read the second part of my answer and look at the links provided.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/453617/20815. One does not simply recommend one-click installers on SF.

Comment: @EEAA I didn't say he *should* I just said he *could* - there was no information about whether this was for dev or prod purposes.I outlined both ways of doing it.