# is Xampp enough For a School Local Web Server?

Tags: php, web-server, xampp, local

So Guys I'm trying to build a website for my school but can be access with no internet cause i will be running it on a virtual host using xampp so if students connect to the router where i run my web server ( Xampp virtual Host ) They can connect and use it for Chatting see latest announcements and share files with others my question is Is Xampp enough for this? and what are the problems i might encounter in the future btw the students enrolled is somewhere 10k - 15k students can a single Xampp Virtual Host handle that? i need tips from you guys to make this work locally offline

btw this is my plan a inforgraph so you guys can understand what I meant,
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrQh5.jpg)

Comment: I find XAMPP frustrating and would avoid it for this sort of usage. It's really better used for single-user local development, IMO.

Comment: In addition to why we can't tell you if a configuration will handle a specific load: please [don't use one-click installers for production](https://serverfault.com/q/453617/37681)

Answer (score 1):

Funny how you paste "no internet needed" all over the infograph. With up to 15k users, I would assume it's not just a local wifi router you put up but you're using the internal wifi network of the school? If so depending on the application one server might not be enough to server all 15k users. If it is indeed a local router with wifi hotspot and only a single class of about 20-30 users will access the server at the same time, I'm sure the XAMPP setup will work fine.

Comment: sorry im new to this but this is what im planning im gonna Connect the machine(server) in a TP Link repeater and from there to a actual wifi hotspot  assuming its for our department only like 1500 students will it work? or atleast can you give me tips how to make this work?

Comment: @Cedrick:  TP LINK *repeater*? Hot spot? 1500 students? If you want to have any success with this, get a professional on board who knows how to scale a Wifi network to this size ...

Comment: Is it 1500 students of 15k students? BIG difference! Either way, one hot spot router is not going to cut it. That will do 10 users max.

Comment: @tom for my first question yes thats 15k because thats the whole university student count, i just assumed if its just gonne be on our Department only for Seniot High school which is 1500 students enrolled just to make it clear for you bro. yah I think im just gonna use a real online webhosting that can handle that and just make the whole thing online haha

Comment: @tom its just an idea for my school project I I What i need to do is that i can prove that it would work well if we set up simple server for testing, then if it works the school will give me budget