# PHP seems to ignore my curl.info of my php.ini

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php.ini

I posted the same question on StackOverflow, but someone told me that I should ask it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894424/php-seems-to-ignore-my-curl-info-of-my-php-ini.

I'm using WAMP on Windows with several version of PHP. The one I currently use is PHP 7.3.12. After following carefully every step of installing the `cacert.pem` file into my WAMP folder, my PHP does not seems to see it. Here's the step I've taken to install it:

- I downloaded the `cacert.pem` file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
- I moved this file into my `extras\ssl` folder of my PHP folder (`C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`)
- I wrote this absolute path into the `php.ini` file from WAMP, after `curl.cainfo` (and I removed the `;` caracter), by left-clicking the WAMP icon>PHP>php.ini. This file is located here: `C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini`.
- Then I restart my WAMP services and it literally copy this file on the `php.ini` file of the PHP version I'm currently using here: `C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\phpForApache.ini`.

Even after theses steps, PHP do not seems to see my cacert file because when I try to `dd(ini_get('curl.cainfo'))` if give me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOYAW.png (sorry, can't post image w/o 10 rep)

Just to be sure, I looked into my `phpinfo()` in the curl section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3EQU.png (sorry, can't post image w/o 10 rep)

But when I dumped my `php.ini` file with this command `dd(file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file()));`, I can clearly see my `curl.cainfo` path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bR1B.png (sorry, can't post image w/o 10 rep)

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but when using GuzzleHTTP from my Laravel projet, I tried giving the library an absolute path `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => 'C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem']);` and it worked. I still want to be able to use it with the `php.ini` file for environnement purpose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clear question, but I'am not sure it's a good fit as WAMP stack is considered dev. Sadly you seem on a gray zone between us and SO. See that for the reason of my comment; https://serverfault.com/questions/453617/why-not-use-a-wamp-stack

Comment: A tip, If it's apache and a cert for it, maybe focus your question on how to install the certificate on apache might help or search on that topic, SF is loaded with question about that

Comment: Hello and thank you for your honest answer. I read your comment and I can understand why this is confusing. I might try to reformulate my question on StackOverflow so that a dev can help me.