# How to restore the error.log functionality in Apache, bitnami Wappstack?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, logging, log-files, bitnami

I am using the Bitnami Wappstack 7.4.10 in windows, with PHP 7.4 and Apache 2.4.46 . By accident I made a script that had an infinite loop that also produced an error in every iteration, so the log file grew to be very large, many gigabytes long. I deleted it, thinking that it would be regenerated automatically, but it was not. Now no error is being logged.

I tried creating one new file, it did not work. I tried coping one of the other .log files and renaming it into that, but it did not work neither. I noticed that the "owner" of the file, in the windows property, is different for those other .log files, than for the ones I did. But I was not able to change that property.

Why is this happening? How do make the logging continue again? How can I limit the log file size so I do not have to deal with a gigabytes long file again?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not use a WAMP stack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453617/why-not-use-a-wamp-stack)

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't do it. I removed the error_log file and restarted the Apache's service and the log file was automatically created. Did you restart the Apache's service for the log to appear? Please note that if the file is removed once the service is running, it won't create a new file automatically.